# Query domain class associations in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.3

I have a few domain classes similar to the following:

```
class Position {
    String code
    String title

    static hasMany = [relations: Relation]
}

class Unit {
    String code
    String title

    static hasMany = [relations: Relation]
}

class Relation {
    Position position
    Unit unit

    static belongsTo = [
        position: Position,
        unit: Unit
    ]
}
```

I am attempting to use criteria to find all positions that **do not** have any relations. I know this can be solved using HQL but I find the criteria to be cleaner when building dynamic criteria versus building a dynamic HQL string.

Is there a way to use criteria to do something like:

```
Position.withCriteria { isNull('relations') }
```

I have tried the above but I always get a list containing 0 elements even though I know there are unrelated positions in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For collections you need to use `isEmpty()` instead of `isNull()`.

```
Position.withCriteria { isEmpty('relations') }
```

Comment: Wow. I have spent hours on this and it was so simple. Thank you so much.